# what difference between firestore transaction.set(ref, data, {merge: true}) and transaction.update(ref, data)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

I was faced with the fact that operations that seem to be the same in functionality lead to different results.

In the case of the `transaction.set(ref, data, {merge: true})`, the result is obtained only from the second execution of the operation, and the `transaction.update(ref, data)` is performed immediately.

All the environment and input data the same in both cases. Maybe there is a difference in runtime?

```
async updateFields(userId: string, storyId: string, allItemsSeen: boolean,
                       lastId?: string | null): Promise<void> {

    await this.db.runTransaction(async (transaction) => {
        const queryRef = this.refs.story(userId, storyId);
        const query = await transaction.get(queryRef);

        const data: any = {[ALL_ITEMS_SEEN]: allItemsSeen};

        if (lastItemSeenId !== undefined) {
            data[LAST_ITEM_SEEN_ID] = lastItemSeenId;
        }

        if (!query.empty) {
            transaction.update(query.docs[0].ref, data); // is performed immediately.
==========================================
            transaction.set(query.docs[0].ref, data, {merge: true}); // the result is obtained only from the second execution of the operation
        } 
    });
}
```

Comment: Wha is "the result" that you're referring to?  It would help if you edit the question to show the code and the resutls that don't make sense to you.

Comment: The result is an update of the field 'allItemsSeen' in the database to the value that is in the parameter. That's all.

Comment: I therefore asked such a question, that, in the operation, which is essentially the same, different behavior occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `update` call will only update the document if it already exists. If the document doesn't yet exist, the `update` call will fail.

The `set` call on the other hand, will create or update the document as needed.

This same distinction applies both in transactions and in regular write operations.

Comment: But this does not explain why these two operations gave different results.

Comment: You might want to read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it's hard to say what problem you now have from the snippets you shared so far.